# Negation `!` in a dplyr pipeline `%>%`

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to use negation in dplyr pipeline?

E.g for

```
df = data.frame(a = c(T,F,F), b = c(T,T,T))
```

I can write

```
!df
```

but I cannot write

```
df %>% !
```

(as `!` is not a function).

In particular, I use `!is.na` a lot, but I am not able to incorporate it into pipelines.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `backticks` around `!`

```
 df %>%
       `!`
 #      a     b
 #[1,] FALSE FALSE
 #[2,]  TRUE FALSE
 #[3,]  TRUE FALSE
```

For `!is.na`

```
 df$a[2] <- NA
 df %>% 
      is.na %>% 
      `!`
 #       a    b
 #[1,]  TRUE TRUE
 #[2,] FALSE TRUE
 #[3,]  TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: what's not working: df |> is.na |> `!``

Answer (score 13):

Note that the piping operator used in dplyr is imported from `magrittr` so for access to the other functions, use

```
library(magrittr)
```

See the `?extact` page for a list of common magrittr-friendly aliases.

In this case `not()` is defined as a alias for `!`

```
df %>% not
```

To make it easier to call !is.na, you could define

```
not_ <- function(x, f) not(f(x))
df %>% not_(is.na)
```